# How many teachers have in a school in a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three model with a has many thorugh association:

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :teachers, through: :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :subjects, through: :school_teacher_subjects   
end


class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :schools, through: :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :subjects, through: :school_teacher_subjects
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord   
    has_many :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :teachers, through: :school_teacher_subjects
    has_many :schools, through: :school_teacher_subjects
end


class SchoolTeacherSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :school
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

I need to know how many teachers a school has, in a optimized query, but i don't know how can i do this

This is the school_teacher_subjects table:

```
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | teacher_id | school_id | subject_id |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |         1 |          1 |
|  2 |          2 |         1 |          1 |
|  3 |          2 |         1 |          2 |
|  4 |          3 |         2 |          1 |
|  5 |          3 |         2 |          2 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I'm need something like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| School name | school city | Teacher count |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| School A    | New York    |             2 |
| School B    | Orlando     |             1 |
+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

The name and city data are stored in School Table

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:
1) Using **rails query**, you need to use **Group** with **Select** + **count** to combine them into one query:

To get only schools with teachers, use **Joins**

```
School.joins(:school_teacher_subjects => [:teacher]).select("schools.id, schools.name, schools.city, count(DISTINCT teachers.id) as teacher_count ").group("schools.id")
```

To get all schools with or without teachers, use **left_outer_joins**:

```
School.left_outer_joins(:school_teacher_subjects => [:teacher]).select("schools.id, schools.name, schools.city, count(DISTINCT teachers.id) as teacher_count ").group("schools.id")
```

2) Another way is to rely on **School Model** when fetching the data by appending the `as_json` in the **School** class as follow *(if you are not fetching large amount)*:

```
def as_json(options = {})
    if options[:index]
      {
          id: id,
          school_name: name,
          city_name: city_name, # in case you have the city name in school class
          teachers: teachers.count
      }
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Then call the model as below:

```
Teacher.as_json(index: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but returns this error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "schools.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: @Eduardorph I have updated the answer to use group_by instead of group, which group the processed results.

Comment: Your first suggestion returns almost the same error:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "school_teacher_subjects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I have updated the joins and show the `id` only for `school_teacher_subjects`

Comment: Now: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'SchoolTeacherSubject' to association named 'teachers'; perhaps you misspelled it?  I tried change to joins(:teacher, :school), but returns: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous

Comment: @Eduardorph I reverted back, I think the error you showed `ERROR: column "school_teacher_subjects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY ` belongs to old answer, because I am not including the **school_teacher_subjects.id"** in an ActiveRecord Group.

Comment: =( Still returning ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "school_teacher_subjects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165253/discussion-between-shiko-and-eduardorph).

Comment: This query returns only schools that have teachers. How can i show the empty schools too?

Comment: Use **left_outer_joins** instead of **joins**